How to apply filters on column with lots of unique values in Pygwalker?
Anyone knows, how to apply regex search to filter all entries do not belong to 2005.
I tried multiple patterns like below but none of it works with Pygwalker

!/2005/
^(?!.2005).
^(?!.\b2005\b).$

Also, seen through some of the posts like Regex: match everything but a specific pattern but no luck
I am using below
pygwalker==0.4.9.13
streamlit==1.40.1
python==3.11


How about ^(?!.*2005)?

^((?!.2005).) . BTW, is there a character in front of the number or the line just starts with the latter? Also ^((?!.2005).).*$

@DuesserBaest, it is working in https://regex101.com/. However, when I am trying the same in Pygwalker it is throwing error like - Invalid Input Error: invalid perl operator: (?!

@Ritesh then apparently lookarounds are not permitted. You could try the verbose: ^(?:[^2]|2[^0]|20[^0]|200[^5])
